# How do I automatically generate dummy data using laravel and visual studio code

Tags: mysql, laravel, visual-studio-code

So in this link, https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding it has a sample algorithm for generating dummy data for our database. I was wondering how I could implement it using Microsoft Visual Studio code? Thanks.

Comment: What are you referring to exactly: how to generate the seeder class using the artisan command, how to write the code? Implementing this using Visual Studio Code is the same as implementing this using any other text editor or IDE (Sublime Text, Atom, etc). Please clarify your question.

Comment: you can't use microsoft visual studio code in here,for dummy data you can use ```faker```

Comment: How to generate the seeder class using the artisan command and how to execute that command. For our database, we used wampserver. For our tables, we used MySQL. Since we need around 2000 records for our data, how will I be able to generate the data required using the seeder class?

Comment: Artisan commands are run from the command line in the Laravel project  directory (so the terminal if your on Linux or OS X, and from the Command Prompt if you're on Windows), that is one thing that may be relevant and is not explicitly stated in the docs. Aside from that the documentation is pretty clear, run the `php artisan make:seeder SomeTableSeeder` to create your class, use [model factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/seeding#using-model-factories) that will generate and insert fake data and then run `php artisan db:seed` to execute the seeder classes and populate the database.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply sir. I would give it a try and add another comment for the results that I will get. Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether laravel 5.1 sources with integrate with visual Studio. But I want to add some comments regarding generating the dummy data. Seeding is good if you want to dump little data which is relevant to meeting the website workflow and hide some gray area. But to create dummy data, you can use packages like "fzaninotto/faker" which provides very powerful source to create lot of data into your DB, along with the facility of using internationalization/locale specific to region eg. fr-France, en-English, in-India etc.